# how to create image carousel (not the regular type) - css / react / npm

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

I have a list of images that i need them to move right every 2 sec (like the image),

and I need it to be infinite carousel (with something like 10 images, when the carousel gets to the last image - start again at the first one).

how can i do it using react & css / sass ?

do you guys know any npm for it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

React Bootstrap has a nice carousel, and some other great components. You can check the installation [here](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/), is very straightforward

After installing you'll need to load the carousel on the component you want, like this

```
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel'

<Carousel>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501854140801-50d01698950b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60"
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
<Carousel>
```

I addded a working example here https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-dubinsky-r6bi6